# Magento 2 Add text in checkout page via XML

Tags: checkout, xml, magento2.2

I'm trying to add custom text in checkout page via XML. I have my custom checkout_index_index.xml file with this inside:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom text here</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

The text is not added. I've tried with a block but an error is displayed.
How can I display a custom text or a CMS Block?

Comment: In which place you want to add your custom text ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `uiComponent` with a custom template:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                        <item name="some_text" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">35</item>
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/some_text</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>

                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/some_text.html

```
<h3>Some text</h3>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Really appreciate to the point answer!

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau It's working. And a new question... If I want to use a CMS block, is there any way to call the block directly from XML? I've seen that the custom file must be HTML. If I use PHTML it doesn't work.

Comment: @mlavela In this case you should create this block in the layout and pass it trough `.phtml` template as a param of your custom UI component, then add this html in your template (`.html`)

Comment: Great answer! I can confirm this works on Magento 2.1.18. Just wondering, is the template required? What if I just want to add a plain word that can be translated?