# How to add custom text block in onpage check-out

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to add custom text block in onepage checkout in #payment page. That block  will use to remind the "discount code" to customer, it's like popup text.

Please check the sample image.

[image]

Comment: explain position via screenshot  and what do you mean by popup text ?

Comment: See this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208702/magento-2-add-text-in-checkout-page-via-xml

Comment: yes @ Hassan....

Comment: Hi @kernel, I like to display like popup text

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Try following way to use magento default popup modal:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/js/view/custom-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-block.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, ko, Component, modal, payment, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_MagentoCommunity/custom-block'
        },
        options: {
            popupModalContent: '#sr-discount-popup'
        },
        shouldShowMessage: ko.observable(false),
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var self = this;
            var subscription = payment.prototype.isVisible.subscribe(function(value){
                if (value) {
                    var popupModalContent = self.options.popupModalContent;
                    var modalOption = {
                        type: 'popup',
                        responsive: true,
                        title: 'Test Title',
                        buttons: [{}],
                        closed: function () {
                            self.shouldShowMessage(false);
                        }
                    };
                    self.shouldShowMessage(true);
                    $(popupModalContent).modal(modalOption);
                    $(popupModalContent).trigger('openModal');
                    subscription.dispose();
                }
            });
            return this;
        },
        getMessage: function () {
            return $t("Don't forget to use discount code");
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/template/custom-block.html

```
<div id="sr-discount-popup" data-bind="visible:shouldShowMessage">
    <span data-bind="text: getMessage()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. @ Sohel

Comment: Please let me know, how to add image instead of text.

Comment: Pass image from php checkout config and added that image in html

Comment: Yeah got it thank you

Comment: @mohana do you manage that?

Comment: Yes @ Sohel. Thank you